# How to find the anti-derivative of $\sin^2(x)$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I already know that this problem can be solved through a trigonometric identity. However, since this is a relatively simple expression, why can’t the antiderivative just be traced back? In such case, the antiderivative would be $\frac{\sin(x)^3}{3 \cos(x)}$. I am aware that this function will be non continuous at certain points. But would it be a valid anti derivative in certain intervals?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by "traced back"? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "traced back". Also, an integral having a simple integrand does not mean it will be easy and/or straighforward to evaluate. Try evaluating $\int\frac{e^x}{x}dx$.

Comment: If tracing back involves recognizing it as the result of a differentiation, well, when have you ever seen this as the result of differentiation? To be sure, if you've differentiated $\frac12x-\frac12\sin x\cos x$ and manipulated the result into $\sin^2x$, then it's legitimate to recognize that and get the antiderivative that way. But not many people are going to recognize that. (I didn't; I had to work it out, even though I've seen this integral many times before.) Nor will doing a simple substitution put it in a recognizable form. So we have to do something more subtle.

Comment: It looks like you want $\int (f(x))^n \ dx = \frac {(f(x))^{n+1}}{(n+1)f'(x)}.$  But that doesn't work.  It is true that $\int (f(x))^n f'(x)\ dx = \frac {(f(x))^{n+1}}{(n+1)}$ but that is not the same thing.  Try taking the derivative of your result.  You will see that something has gone wrong.

Comment: Your antiderivative is not correct because you forgot that the quotient rule existed :)

Comment: To answer your question directly: No, it is not an antiderivative on any interval. The derivative of $f(x)/g(x)$ is not $f'(x)/g'(x)$. Have you learned the product/quotient rule?

Comment: It's correct to say that the integral of $\sin^2x\cos x$ is $\frac13\sin^3x$. But that doesn't mean that the integral of $\sin^2x$ is $\frac13\sin^3x/\cos x$. That reasoning would only be valid if $\cos x$ were constant, which it's not.

Comment: Your proposed antiderivative is incorrect.$$\begin{align}\frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{\sin^3(x)}{3\cos(x)}\right]&=\frac13\frac{d}{dx}\left[\tan(x)\sin^2(x)\right]\\&=\frac13\left(\sec^2(x)\sin^2(x)+2\tan(x)\sin(x)\cos(x)\right)\\&=\frac13\left(\tan^2(x)+2\sin^2(x)\right)\\&\neq\sin^2(x)\end{align}$$

Comment: In light of others' points, the closest thing to your idea is IBP viz.$$\int\sin^2xdx=-\sin x\cos x+\int\cos^2xdx=-\sin x\cos x+x-\int\sin^2xdx$$so$$\int\sin^2xdx=\frac{x-\sin x\cos x}{2}+C.$$